# Remove old Google Analytics code on a Wordpress install

Tags: google-analytics

We have recently started maintaining a website built by another person. We found out that there are two GA codes on the sites. For one of them we have the login credentials. But the other one is a bit of mystery - the old developer has left it behind with no way to delete it from Google side, we have no idea of the login details and not able to get them. So, we decided to delete the older tracking code.
We have deactivated plugins on the site, we have checked the usual places - header.php, footer.php and scanned the entire directory for the old GA string, we cannot locate the string. We are not tech savy, we are more on the content side and know a bit of css, html, js.

How does and where does Wordpress store GA tracking codes? Does it store it exactly as we see it on the dashboard? What and where should we search in the files for?

We are using Neve theme.

Is there a way to set the tracking code to be disabled at all times?

Thank you.

Comment: Check for the code in your database. Start with the options table.

Comment: "How does and where does Wordpress store GA tracking codes?" It doesn't. If there's a tracking code it's been added by a theme or plugin. "Does it store it exactly as we see it on the dashboard?" Where are you seeing it on the dashboard?